# Is accessing a static constexpr member from a placement new a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-members, placement-new, constant-expression

To clarify, is the following program well-formed?

```
#include <new>
char foo[32];
struct bar {
        static constexpr int foobar = 42;
};

int main() 
{
        auto p = new (foo) bar();
        static_assert(p->foobar == 42);
}
```

[gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/5fz5q78h6) and [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/q3Tvcra3M) accept, but [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/8fEqEv3Kj) rejects with the error
`read of non-constexpr variable 'p' is not allowed in a constant expression`, who is right?

Comment: This comes down to whether dereferencing a non-constexpr pointer to access a name that resolves to a compile time constant is considered a compile time constant. You get similar sorts of errors with a `case p->foobar:` statement.

Comment: I think rather it comes down to if it is necessary to dereference a non-constexpr pointer to access a static constexpr member variable with the syntax provided

Comment: A similar thing is done by libraries such as boost/hana for constexpr accessing operators on map, where the "this" pointer is never touched. Does using the syntax provided necessitate touching the "this" pointer?

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to:

```
auto constexpr p = new (foo) bar();
```

Then the clang error message becomes clearer:

```
<source>:12:24: error: constexpr variable 'p' must be initialized by a constant expression
        auto constexpr p = new (foo) bar();
                       ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:28: note: dynamic memory allocation is not permitted in constant expressions until C++20
        auto constexpr p = new (foo) bar();
                           ^
```

So the answer depends on the C++ language version.

Comment: in c++20 clang still rejects (to be clear, I mean clang still rejects my version, not yours)

Comment: also, we don't need to read the value of ```p``` to get access to the static constexpr member, so p need not be a constant expression, maybe

Comment: @JakeSchmidt https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.ref#footnote-59

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Nice find, I think that might be the answer, annoyingly, it seems that clang is right

Comment: @LanguageLawyer If that footnote means `p` needs to be a constant expression, wouldn't `auto p = bar(); static_assert(p.foobar == 42);` also be an error? But it's not, and Clang accepts it.

Comment: @cigien Which bullet in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5 makes `p` from `p.foobar` not constant expression

Comment: @LanguageLawyer None. IIUC, the bullet that allows `new` expressions doesn't count, presumably because the lifetime of the expression that allocates memory for `p` doesn't extend to the `static_assert`? Also, you seem to know the answer to the OP's question; why not write an answer?